# Prove that $f$ Is Continuous $\Longleftrightarrow f(x) \le M||x||$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose that $E$ is a normed vector space over $\mathbb R$ and $f$ is a linear functional on $E$.  I forgot how to prove that:
$$f \text{ is continuous }\Longrightarrow f(x) \le M||x||$$
If $E = \mathbb R^n$, then the set $A = \{ \, x : ||x|| = 1 \, \}$ is closed and bounded, therefore compact.  Thus, $f(A)$ is also bounded.  Then, write:
$$|f(x)| = \left| \, f \left( \frac{x}{||x||} \right) \, \right| ||x|| \le M||x||$$
I don't think this characterization of compactness is valid on an arbitrary normed vector space.  Can you give me some clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given some $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $\|y\| < \delta$ then $|f(y)| < \epsilon$.

Then for any $x$, setting $y=(\delta/2) x/\|x\|$ (so that $\|y\|=\delta/2$) implies $|f(y)| < \epsilon$. Rewriting gives
$$|f(y)| = \frac{\delta}{2\|x\|} |f(x)| < \epsilon \implies |f(x)| < M\|x\|$$
for $M=2\epsilon/\delta$. Note that this holds for arbitrary $x$.

Comment: Okay, TY.  I overcomplicated things.